# Apache NTLM not authenicating domain username/password.

Tags: apache-2.4, samba, ntlm, winbind

I have a centos box and I am trying to setup NTLM authenication for apache. I have the linux box on the AD domain already and able to get user and group info using the wbinfo command.

I have the ntlm.conf httpd configuration setup as follows

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/auth">
Options Indexes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
AllowOverride all
AuthName "NTLM"
Require user acorp
NTLMBasicAuthoritative on
AuthType NTLM
NTLMAuth on
NTLMAuthHelper "/usr/bin/ntlm_auth --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp"
</Directory>
```

When I run the command /usr/bin/ntlm_auth --username acorp --domain acorp.local, I get NT_STATUS_OK, however, when I go to the https page, it does not take the username and password. I cannot see any error messages on any of the log files.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To see what error you are getting in logs, add "LogLevel debug" in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

To enable AD SSO auth on CentOS machine, try steps in link below:
https://hemakhema.blogspot.ae/2017/07/enable-sso-login-in-linux.html